# Smarty and Mosaico - compatibility?

Tags: smarty, mosaico

Seeing a lot of smarty errors in Drupal log file for mailings using Mosaico template - looks like an error for every message sent so thousands filling log files.

Nothing obvious in Mosaico template but thinking it must be a conflict with use of { } in each case.  Smarty logic in the template that I can see.

should smarty be turned off in civicrm.settings.php if using Mosaico?

Comment: What is the version of Mosaico and flexmailer ext ? Are they on latest?

Comment: yes, I believe these are current - flexmailer 0.2-alpha5 and mosaico 2.0-beta4.1528762072

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Smarty and Mosaico together.  Tim Otten [presents a long answer why](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/pull/252#issuecomment-392979047) if you want details!

Comment: OK, good to know.  Should there be a warning in system status?    Painful error to find after the fact.

Comment: Not a bad idea - but to be clear - are you using Smarty logic in Mosaico? Or do you have curly brackets that make Mosaico *think* you're using Smarty? Since Mosaico users can still send traditional CiviMails, it'd be good to make sure they could use Smarty when doing so.

Comment: No Smarty logic to my knowledge in Mosaico maling template - only whatever Mosaico would use in its templates.  Agree that it would be too bad to have to disable Smarty for all uses even if not Mosaico.

Comment: Hmm - @DaveT are you using the latest version of Mosaico 2.x?  I would have assumed that Flexmailer would have prevented these errors.  Do you have "View on Website" in use?  Is it possible that the Smarty errors appear when someone views a Mosaico mailing on the website?  I believe there's an open issue for that.

Comment: Hmmm, Hmmm - just updated to most recent (stable) version of Mosaico - 2.0.1556289017 - Initial (very limited) testing does not show smarty errors.  Perhaps fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://github.com/mjwconsult/civicrm-mosaico_smarty
I need to upgrade my system to try it out, let me know if it works.